# how can I set UTC timezone in cron job

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I have tried using this code, but it didn't work,it should run when UTC time 1 pm and according to IST time 6:30 pm, but it is not working at that time

Versions are mentioned below

Node - 10.16.0

node-cron - 2.0.3

```
cron.schedule('0 0 13 * * *', () => { }, {
  scheduled: true,
  timezone: "UTC"
})
```

Comment: Please explain what didn't work. also add what you expected it to do and which versions of packages you are running, also the NodeJS version is important.

Comment: Hello @mitchken, I have edited my question

Comment: Set `utcOffset` to 0 with NodeJS CronJob: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron